# How do you disable a MenuItem if a user is not logged in?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I disable an  if the user is not logged in?

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Customizations.aspx" Text="Customizations" Enabled="<%# Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated %>" />
```

Doesn't work, even if I specify Page.DataBind() in the Page_Load method.

```
<% if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { %>
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Customizations.aspx" Text="Customizations" />
<% } %>
```

Gives the error: Parser Error Message: Code blocks are not supported in this context.

I tried adding an ID attribute, and it gives an error saying it isn't a supported attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While trying to make webforms like winforms, Microsoft came up short and hasn't faithfully represented a lot of the properties in the winforms MenuItem object, specifically the Visible property. They've also sealed the class barring the ability to work around this oversight through polymorphism.

It would be brilliant to be able to do something like this:

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Customizations.aspx" Text="Customizations" Visible="<%# HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated %>/>
```

You're unfortunately probably going to have to resort to either building or modifying your list in the code-behind.

Comment: Thanks, I resorted to modifying my list in the code-behind :(

Answer (score 0):

I would say default the ones that may be in question for users by setting Visible="false" and for the ones that should be visible, set Visible=true in code...  there isn't any good inline support for this in web forms.

HTH

Comment: How would you set Visible=true in the code? Since you can't assign an ID to the element, there seems to be no way of modifying it.

Comment: Also, there is no Visible property.

Comment: Hello,

OK, yes, my apologies... I thought there was but yes this verifies it:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem_properties%28VS.80%29.aspx

So it does seem a little more limiting than I thought it was.  You can use Menu.FindItem to find items through the value path (each menu item has a value and this value can be used as a path).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.finditem%28VS.80%29.aspx

Then, you can either dynamically add items, or add them to the list and dynamically remove.